# Advances MySQL Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have MySQL table that contains all messages from user to user:

```
id | to_id /*user_id*/ | from_id /*user_id*/
 1 |  32               |  54
 2 |  54               |  32
 3 |  32               |  54
```

The goal is get MySQL answer like list of dialogs user_id - user_id ordered by date. But if i do sql query:

```
select * from messages group by to_id, from_id
```

i will get

```
 to_id /*user_id*/ | from_id /*user_id*/
  32               |  54
  54               |  32
```

But first and second string is the same dialog. How can i group this records?

Comment: How do you want it to look like?

Comment: can you specify the desired output of yours

Comment: i want to get answer with id of last messages of each dialogs, in this way i can order it by date, paginate, get collocutors ids and other things.

Comment: Do you have a datetime or timestamp column?

Comment: yep, but it doesn't matter is't it? :) swemon already found solution. Look below.

Comment: I see an answer but I see no order by date there. If dates are not important for you, don't mention them in the question.

Comment: don't matter because i need the answer how to group in dialogs. This is the goal. Ordering the easiest thing in this problem. So it's don't matter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(from_id, to_id), GREATEST(from_id, to_id) FROM messages
```

Comment: @AlexanderBochkarev: Gosh, I thought it would be quite self-evident.  [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) respectively return the minimum and maximum values amongst their arguments, so irrespective of who messaged whom the users are guaranteed to appear in the same order.  `DISTINCT` then removes duplicates from the resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your messages table includes a field called something like `message_date`, try:

```
select to_id, from_id, max(message_date) latest_date
from (select to_id, from_id, message_date
      from messages where to_id >= from_id
      union all
      select from_id to_id, to_id from_id, message_date
      from messages where to_id < from_id) m
group by to_id, from_id
order by 3 desc, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to store the `origin_id` of the original message the user replied

Then you will have a way to group the records by `origin_id`

I dont see any other way with just a origin and destination id

Comment: (The only other way i see is to group by "object" but string comparisons are a bit slow)

Answer (score 0):

```
select small_id, big_id, count(*) from
(select id, 
    case when to_id < from_id then to_id else from_id end as small_id, 
    case when to_id < from_id then from_id else to_id end as big_id
from messages) as a 
group by small_id, big_id
```